# Finding $\partial F/\partial y$ if $F(x,v)=F(u,z)$ and ...

Tags: partial-derivative, chain-rule

I'm here trying to solve the equation (following the solution in Jaynes' *Probability Theory* book) $F(F(x,y),z)=F(x,F(y,z))$.  Suppose $u = F(x,y)$ and $v=F(y,z)$ and we want $\frac{\partial F(x,v)}{\partial y}$.  We let $F_1(x,y)=\frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial x}$ and $F_2(x,y)=\frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial y}$.  Here is my calculation, trying to use the chain rule as explicitly as I can in order to find out where I'm going wrong.

$$\frac{\partial F(x,v)}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial{x}}\biggr\rvert_{x=x,y=v}\frac{\partial x}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial v}\biggr\rvert_{x=x,y=v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$$

Here $\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}=0$ and $\frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial v}=1$ and $\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=F_2(y,z)\frac{\partial y}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=F_2(y,z)$ .  Putting this into the equation above,

$$\frac{\partial F(x,v)}{\partial y} = 0+1\cdot F_2(y,z)$$

However, in the book he suggests that the left-hand side is equal to $F_2(x,v)F_1(y,z)$.

Let me know if I'm somehow misusing the chain rule or making any other mistake.

(Note, I think this is pretty neat, it's apparently called The Associativity Equation and was studied by Abel and given an 11-page solution without assuming differentiability by Aczel.  In reasoning from "first principles" about probabilities Jaynes produces it as the necessary form of a probability function.)

Comment: If you think of $F_{i}(x,y)$ as meaning the partial derivative of $F(u_1,u_2)$ with respect to $u_i$ evaluated at $(x,y)$, then this will probably make more sense. So $\frac{\partial F(x,v)}{\partial y}=\partial_{2}F(x,F(y,z))\partial_{1}F(y,z)$, dropping the terms equal to $0$ in the differentiation. This is exactly the author's answer. When you differentiate $F(x,v)$ wrt $y$, you mean $\left.\dfrac{\partial F(u_1,u_2)}{\partial u_2}\right|_{(u_1,u_2)=(x,v)}\dfrac{\partial{v}}{\partial{y}}$, dropping some of the terms equal to $0$ again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Correct application of the chain rule

Differentiating $F(x,F(y,z))$ with respect to $y$ we have:

$$F_2(x,F(y,z))F_1(y,z)$$

That is (applying the chain rule) we differentiate the outer $F$ with respect to its second argument (because there is a $y$ in there), and multiply it by the derivative of the inner $F$ with respect to its first argument ($y$).

---

Maybe this will help understand how we are applying the chain rule here:

Let $f(y)=F(x,y)$ and let $g(y)=F(y,z)$. Then

- $f(g(y))=F(x,F(y,z))$
- $f'(y)=F_2(x,y)$
- $g'(y)=F_1(y,z)$

We want the derivative of $f(g(y))$. By the chain rule (for compositions of functions of single variables) this is $$f'(g(y))g'(y)=F_2(x,F(y,z))F_1(y,z).$$

---

### Where you went wrong

The first term in your derivative is unnecessary (because as you say it is zero). However, it is not true that what you have called  $$\frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial v}\biggr\rvert_{x=x,y=v}$$ is equal to 1. Actually, $$\frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial v}\biggr\rvert_{x=x,y=v}=F_2(x,y)$$

Comment: Whoever corrected my post deleted the variable there.  I've corrected the correction and, although I could easily be mistaken, it seems to me the right value is still 1.

Comment: Ahh, right, ok, I see.

Comment: So I'm still not totally getting it, both in a tedious way and in an intuitive one.  If I just run fast and loose, I get that we take the derivative of the outter w.r.t. $y$ plugging back in, getting $F_2(x,F(x,y))$  The next part, though, I would think would be $F_2(y,z)$.

Comment: In the tedious way, I don't see how we get $\frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial{v}}$ and in this case I have no good intuitions.  I would think to do this you do partial w.r.t. $x$, then $x$ w.r.t. $v$ which is 0, fine; then do partial w.r.t. $y$ then $y$ w.r.t. $v$ and that last part I don't see how to do.

Comment: See my edit where I have shown that the problem is really just a simple application of the basic chain rule for single variable functions. By the way the notation $\frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial{v}}$ in your comment above does not really make sense. The variable $z$ does not appear in $F(x,y)$ so that is zero. I think you need to get a better grasp of how to correctly use the mathematical notation for functions and partial derivatives. Here, rather than using the Leibniz notation $\partial F(x,y)/\partial y$ etc, it is easier to use Lagrange's notation $F_2(x,y)$ etc.